# Posting to Popup Controller Before the Parent Page Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

**How do I force a popup page to post to its controller first before posting to the parent controller?** The popup page is setting up some session variables that would be used in the parent page. When the user double click on the grid on the pop-up page, it goes directly to the parent controller instead of going to the child controller.

Here is the parent where the popup is being called

```
//Javascript to open the popup window

@using (Html.BeginForm("Student", "StudentPage", FormMethod.Get, new { onsubmit = "", id = "student" }))
{
//where the popup window is located
}
```

Here is the popup form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "StudentInformation", FormMethod.Post, new {id="StudentSearchForm"}))
{ 
   @(Html
    .Telerik()
    .Grid((IEnumerable<OverrideStudent>)SessionWrapper.Student.OtherStudentSelected)
    .Name("StudentData")
    .DataKeys(Keys =>
    {
        Keys.Add(c => c.StudentID);
    })
    .DataBinding(databinding => databinding.Server())
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.StudentId)
            .Title("Student ID")
            .Width(15)
            .Sortable(true)
            .Filterable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.StudentDescription)
            .Title("Description")
            .Width(65)
            .Sortable(true)
            .Filterable(false);
        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Custom("AddStudent")
                .Text("Select")
                .DataRouteValues(routes =>
                {
                    routes.Add(o => o.StudentID).RouteKey("StudentID");
                    routes.Add(o => o.StudentDescription).RouteKey("StudentDescription");
                })
                .Action("Student", "StudentInfo");
             .HtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "PostData(this);StudentSelectClick(this)" });

        }).Width(20);
    }).ClientEvents(clients => clients
            .OnComplete("OnComplete")
        //.OnDataBinding("DataBinding")
        //.OnDataBound("onRowDataBound")
            .OnRowSelected("StudentDoubleClick")
            )
    .Sortable()
    .Selectable()
    .Filterable(filtering => filtering
                .Enabled(true)
    .Footer(true)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "padding-right: 0.0em;" }))
}
```

//This is the script that handles that double click:

```
function StudentDoubleClick(e) {
        var fromCourse = "@SessionWrapper.Student.FromCoursePage";
        var fromList = "@SessionWrapper.Student.FromListingPage";
        if (fromCourse  == "True") {
            $('tr', this).live('dblclick', function () {
                alert("Inside TR count = " + count);
                count = count + 1;
                DoSearchStudent(e);
            });
        }

        if (fromList == "True") {
            $('tr', this).live('dblclick', function () {
                DoSearchStudent(e);
            });
        }
    }



function DoSearchStudent(e) {
        var row = e.row;
        var StudentID = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
        var StudentDescription = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
        //  alert(procCodeDesc);
        var data = { "StudentID": StudentID, "StudentDescription": StudentDescription, "action": "Double Click" };
        var url = '@Url.Action("Student", "StudentInfo")';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                window.top.location.href = window.top.location.href;
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("An error has occured and the window will not be closed.");

            }
        });
    }
```

//This is the controller that I need to go to first

```
public class StudentInfoController : Controller
    {
        .......

    public string Student(string StudentID, string StudentDescription, string action)
        {
            if (StudentDescription != null)
            {
                StudentDescription = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(StudentDescription);
            }

            try
            {
                RedirectToAction("AddStudent", "StudentInfo", new { StudentID = StudentID, StudentDescription = StudentDescription, action = action });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "Error " + e.ToString(); 
            }

            return "Success";
        }
}
```

After the double click, it goes directly to the controller below instead. AS a result, my variables are not being set resulting in null exception.

```
public class StudentPageController : Controller
    {
        .......

    public string Student(string StudentID, string StudentDescription, Student Students)
        {
            ...........
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a timing issue. When the user close the popup window, the popup thread is not done executing. At the same time, another thread starts to run, and not all the session variables are set as of yet. Before closing the popup window, I added a 1 second delay. 
setTimeout('StudentWindow.close()', 1000);